I want an NPM library that takes my controller and service functions away from the main application
My structure in my original app is as follows:
Folder Structure

My controllers/index.js has this:
module.exports.userController = require("./user.controller");  

My functions inside the user.controller are set up this way
const getUserById = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  var result = await userService.someService(req.body);
  res
    .status(httpStatus.OK)
    .send(responsebody(true, result, "Data fetched successfully", res?.tokens));
};

module.exports = {
  getUserById,
};

My routes.js requires this:
const userController = require("../../controllers/user.controller");  

Then my route runs it like this:
router.route("/users").get(userController.getUserById);

My NPM Library should have a similar structure so I import it using this:
const { userController } = require("@ORG_NAME/NPM_PACKAGE_NAME");

I am currently getting this error:
back/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:216
        throw new Error(msg);
        ^

Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]

After some debugging, I have at least figured out that userController.getUserById is not being called because the console.log message inside the function is not being output. Furthermore, the error seems to be something related to exporting.
My NPM library's root index.js file has:
module.exports = {
  userController: require("./controllers").userController,
};

